# Reset Mac OS X (Snow Leopard) File Permissions -- All Files

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, permissions

Is there a script or process completely reset **all** file system file permissions to factory default? (Less restoring from a image backup or reinstalling the OS).

I’ve affected all files from `/` to “Applications” and home folder and all contents. (*Everything*)

I’ve tried to use the “Disk Utility”’s First Aid “Repair Disk Permissions” but it didn’t seem to touch or affect everything; some but not all. I’ve ran it twice so far.

I’ve seen [this thread—“Fixing mac user file permissions, not the system”](https://superuser.com/questions/143529/fixing-mac-user-file-permissions-not-the-system)—but it’s not quite the something.

The reason for all of this is I accidentally ran a `chmod` on all files (as `sudo`). Working too fast, now I’m in a hole.

Comment: Which files don't seem to be affected? Only the home folders, or also others?

Answer (score 1):

Reboot your machine from the Mac OS X install media and do a verify/repair permissions on your boot drive. This should fix your problems.

Believe it or not, this is not all that uncommon of an occurrence. While the system is booted, diskutil can't fix the OS partition.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion, based entirely on a guess, is that your `Repair` option is not working because the files have the "wrong" permissions to allow the repair to work correctly.

This is not a good position to be in because you have no idea about the stability of the system.

I'd do an `Archive and Install` installation of OS X (which I guess is what @Chris suggested).